# SocialAuth Implementation

Tags: openid, socialauth

Hi
I am implementing socialAuth code using the code provided in the following link.
http://code.google.com/p/socialauth/wiki/GettingStarted.

But when I use provider object (of class AuthProvider). It gives me compilation error during compiling verifyResult method. If somebody has already implemented. 
Please help.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got the answer my self. I had to register with Google and get consumer key and secret.

Got the contactlist of Yahoo and getting some issue while gmail contacts. Anybody used the social auth API?

Comment: I am looking at socialauth because I do not like to reinvent wheels.

Comment: I got contactlist of gmail now. Please let me know if you find anything more interesting about this.

Comment: I successfully implemented this at https://www.gogreenpost.com/referfriend/. For me it works great! I am using it along with Spring Framework. You need any help?

Comment: @Vikas It would be great help from you if you update your answer with information to elaborate that how to get contact list of different domains?